# Download githubarchive data with php and httpclient

Tags: php, symfony, github-archive

i'm trying to download gz file locally from githubarchive with httpclient in php.
When i execute a wget in terminal, the gz is extracted and each folders are downloaded on my computer.
When i do the same in php code, i encounter a 404 each time.

Bellow, my code :

```
//Symfony\Component\HttpClient\HttpClient;
$httpClient = HttpClient::create();
$response = $httpClient->request('GET', "https://data.gharchive.org/2015-01-01-{0..23}.json.gz");

if (200 !== $response->getStatusCode()) {

    throw new \Exception('status code = ' . $response->getStatusCode());
}
```

when i call wget https://data.gharchive.org/2015-01-01-{0..23}.json.gz in console, every files in gz are downloaded on my computer.

Maybe can i use curl but i have already used it with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{0..23}` is a feature of bash called brace expansion. You'll need to recreate this functionality in PHP with something like

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++) {
     $response = $httpClient->request('GET', "https://data.gharchive.org/2015-01-01-{$i}.json.gz");
    ...
}
```